# WAITFOR DELAY doesn't act separately within each WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, delay, wait

I've been teaching myself to use WHILE loops and decided to try making a fun Russian Roulette simulation. That is, a query that will randomly SELECT (or PRINT) up to 6 statements (one for each of the chambers in a revolver), the last of which reads "you die!" and any prior to this reading "you survive."

I did this by first creating a table `#Nums` which contains the numbers 1-6 in random order. I then have a WHILE loop as follows, with a BREAK if the chamber containing the "bullet" (1) is selected (I know there are simpler ways of selecting a random number, but this is adapted from something else I was playing with before and I had no interest in changing it):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #Nums ([Num] INT)
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @Limit INT = 6
DECLARE @Number INT

WHILE @Count <= @Limit
BEGIN
SET @Number = ROUND(RAND(CONVERT(varbinary,NEWID()))*@Limit,0,1)+1
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Num] FROM #Nums WHERE [Num] = @Number)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Nums VALUES(@Number)
SET @Count += 1
END
END

DECLARE @Chamber INT

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
  SET @Chamber = (SELECT TOP 1 [Num] FROM #Nums)
    IF @Chamber = 1
    BEGIN
      SELECT 'you die!' [Unlucky...]
      BREAK
    END
  SELECT
   'you survive.' [Phew...]
  DELETE FROM #Nums WHERE [Num] = @Chamber
END

DROP TABLE #Nums
```

This works fine, but the results all appear instantaneously, and I want to add a delay between each one to add a bit of tension.

I tried using WAITFOR DELAY as follows:

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
  SET @Chamber = (SELECT TOP 1 [Num] FROM #Nums)
    IF @Chamber = 1
    BEGIN
      SELECT 'you die!' [Unlucky...]
      BREAK
    END
  SELECT
   'you survive.' [Phew...]
  DELETE FROM #Nums WHERE [Num] = @Chamber
END
```

I would expect the WAITFOR DELAY to initially cause a 3 second delay, then for the first SELECT statement to be executed and for the text to appear in the results grid, and then, assuming the live chamber was not selected, for there to be another 3 second delay and so on, until the live chamber is selected.

However, before anything appears in my results grid, there is a delay of 3 seconds per number of SELECT statements that are executed, after which all results appear at the same time.
I tried using PRINT instead of SELECT but encounter the same issue.

Clearly there's something I'm missing here - can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The better question is, why are you doing this in SQL? This is clearly something that should be application logic.

Comment: @Larnu Ah yes, I'm well aware of that, I'm just having some fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called buffering. The server doesn't want to return an only partially full response because most of the time, there's all of the networking overheads to account for. Lots of very small packets is more expensive than a few larger packets<sup>1</sup>.

If you use `RAISERROR` (don't worry about the name here where we're using `10`) you can specify `NOWAIT` to say "send this immediately". There's no equivalent with `PRINT` or returning result sets:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

CREATE TABLE #Nums ([Num] INT)
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
DECLARE @Limit INT = 6
DECLARE @Number INT

WHILE @Count <= @Limit
BEGIN
SET @Number = ROUND(RAND(CONVERT(varbinary,NEWID()))*@Limit,0,1)+1
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [Num] FROM #Nums WHERE [Num] = @Number)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Nums VALUES(@Number)
SET @Count += 1
END
END

DECLARE @Chamber INT

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03'
  SET @Chamber = (SELECT TOP 1 [Num] FROM #Nums)
    IF @Chamber = 1
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('you die!, Unlucky',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
      BREAK
    END
   RAISERROR('you survive., Phew...',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
  DELETE FROM #Nums WHERE [Num] = @Chamber
END

DROP TABLE #Nums
```

As Larnu already aluded to [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614041/waitfor-delay-doesnt-act-seperately-within-each-while-loop#comment97922024_55614041), this isn't a *good* use of T-SQL.

SQL is a set-oriented language. We try *not* to write procedural code (do this, then do that, then run this block of code multiple times). We try to give the server as much as possible in a single query and let *it* work out how to process it. Whilst T-SQL *does* have language support for loops, we try to avoid them if possible.

---

<sup>1</sup>I'm using packets *very* loosely here. Note that it applies the same optimizations no matter what networking (or no-networking-local-memory) option is actually being used to carry the connection between client and server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; I'll give RAISERROR a go. I know T-SQL isn't the best language for this, but I was just setting a challenge to myself.

Comment: TDS is a packet-based protocol, so no real need for the footnote. Even when connecting through local memory, the data is shuffled around in packets (which is why, even there, setting `Packet Size` can affect performance) and lots of small packets have measurably more overhead than fewer big ones. This is in addition to any packeting/buffering done by the underlying layer.

Comment: Upon investigation, it seems the ```WITH NOWAIT``` after the ```'You die!'``` error is superfluous, as this will always be the last loop, so there are not multiple delays to accumulate.

Comment: @Simmo33 - yes, in that case, but I was just showing the "here's how to send something immediately" which I was applying where you currently had `SELECT`s trying to send things.